# Cross Correlation (CCF) in R for each ID / by ID

Tags: r, group-by, cross-correlation

I am quite new to R. My data looks (simplified) like this:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4)
Affect <- c(0.8, 0.5, NA, 0.8, 0.2, 0.1, 0.7, 1.1, 0.9, 0.5, 0.3, NA, 0.9)
Paranoia <-  c(0.9, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1, NA, 0.3, 0.1, 0.9, 1.5, 0.4, 0.1, 0.6)
df <- cbind(ID, Affect, Paranoia)
```

What I want calculate a cross correlation in R in order to find out if affect preceeds paranoia or the other way round. 
How can I do this? I tried several ways but never succeeded. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you need `library(tseries);lapply(split(df[-1], df$ID), function(x) {x1 <- replace(x, is.na(x), 0); ccf(x1$Affect, x1$Paranoia)})` assuming `df <- data.frame(ID, Affect,  Paranoia)`

Comment: Thank you akrun! The error message appears: "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" - how can I handle that?

Comment: In my comment if you checked I used data.frame `df <- data.frame(ID, Affect, Paranoia)`

Comment: Ah yes, thank you. Now R gives me another error message: "error in split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...) : 
  group length is 0 but data length is > 0"

Comment: With your example, sorry not getting any error for me

Comment: The example works for me too but something must be wrong in the big data... mmh. Thank you anyways for your help.

Comment: ok, please show an example that gives an error

Comment: Ah, I found the spelling error. Corrected it, now R says: "Error in plot.window(...) : finite 'ylim' values necessary
Additonal: Warnings:
1: In min(x) : no not-missing argument for min; give Inf back
2: In max(x) :
 error in plot.window(...) : finite 'ylim' values necessary

Comment: Please check for IDs, where all the 'Affect' or 'Paranoia' are NA.  I changed it to 0, but still it could result in error

Comment: e.g. `ccf(rep(0, 3), rep(0, 3))#
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values`  Please correct for the NA or remove the IDs where all values are NA, it should work

Comment: Sorry, as I am new to R - is there an easy way to remove all the IDs where all values are NA? Because the dataset has more than 20000 values..

Comment: I posted a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can remove the 'ID's having `all` of 'Affect' or 'Paranoia' as `NA`, then `replace` the remaining NA with 0 (`replace_na`) and apply the `ccf`

```
library(tseries)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
out <- df %>%
         group_by(ID) %>%
         filter(!(all(is.na(Affect))|all(is.na(Paranoia)))) %>% 
         mutate_at(vars(Affect, Paranoia), replace_na, 0) %>% 
         summarise(ccfout = list(ccf(Affect, Paranoia)))


out$ccfout[[1]]
#
#Autocorrelations of series ‘X’, by lag

#    -3     -2     -1      0      1      2      3 
#-0.264 -0.078  0.575  0.229 -0.246 -0.521  0.305 
out$ccfout[[3]]

#Autocorrelations of series ‘X’, by lag

#    -3     -2     -1      0      1      2      3 
#-0.163  0.449  0.408 -0.735 -0.490  0.286  0.245
```

---

Or using `group_split/map`

```
library(purrr)
df %>%
    group_split(ID) %>% 
    map(~ .x %>% 
            mutate_at(vars(Affect, Paranoia), replace_na, 0) %>% 
        {ccf(.$Affect, .$Paranoia)})
#[[1]]

#Autocorrelations of series ‘X’, by lag

#    -3     -2     -1      0      1      2      3 
#-0.264 -0.078  0.575  0.229 -0.246 -0.521  0.305 

#[[2]]

#Autocorrelations of series ‘X’, by lag

#0 
#1 

#[[3]]

#Autocorrelations of series ‘X’, by lag

#    -3     -2     -1      0      1      2      3 
#-0.163  0.449  0.408 -0.735 -0.490  0.286  0.245 

#[[4]]

#Autocorrelations of series ‘X’, by lag

#    -1      0      1 
#-0.289  0.954 -0.636
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(ID, Affect, Paranoia)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204372/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-cross-correlation-ccf-in-r-for-each-id-by-id).